# Proving $\frac{1}{x}\overset{x\to a}{\longrightarrow}\frac{1}{a}$ (the choice of $\delta$)

Tags: calculus, limits

In proving the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac {1}{x}=\frac {1}{a}$ using $\epsilon - \delta $, I have noticed that $\delta=\min \{1, \frac {\epsilon}{a}\} $, but why min-function? I really do not get the point of using such function, why not just $\frac {\epsilon}{a} $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that if $|x-a|<\delta$, then 
$$\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}\right|=\frac{|a-x|}{|a||x|}<\varepsilon$$
Of course $|a-x|<\delta$, but we also need to bound $|x|$ from below to make the denominator far away from $0$. This can be done, because we implicitly assume $a \ne 0$, so if we make $x$ close to $a$ then it will necessarily be far from $0$.
If we choose $|x-a|<\frac{1}{2}|a|$, then by the triangle inequality we have $|x|>\frac{1}{2}|a|$.
So, assuming $\delta < \frac{1}{2}|a|$, 
$$\frac{|a-x|}{|a||x|}<\frac{\delta}{\frac{1}{2}|a|^{2}}$$
If we also have $\delta < \frac{\varepsilon|a|^{2}}{2}$, then the RHS is $<\varepsilon$. In summary, if we choose
$$\delta = \min\left\{\frac{|a|}{2},\frac{|a|^{2}}{2}\varepsilon\right\}$$
then $|1/x - 1/a|<\varepsilon$. Equivalently, we could choose 
$$\frac{2\delta}{|a|} = \min\left\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{|a|}\right\}$$
(which might explain the answer you have)

Answer (score 1):

The first question to ask, actually, is why $\delta$ should be a function of $\epsilon$.

The answer to that question is that when taking limits of a function such
as $f(x)=\frac1x,$ there's no "universal" $\delta$ that will work for *every* $\epsilon.$ Try any particular fixed value of $\delta,$ and there will be some $\epsilon$ so small that this fixed $\delta$ will not work.
We need somehow to account for the fact that the possible choices of $\delta$ are all within a smaller and smaller interval around zero as we look at smaller and smaller values of $\epsilon$.

So we come up with a function $g$ such that as long as we use $g(\epsilon)$
as the value of $\delta,$ we'll be able to prove that
$a-\delta < x < a+\delta \implies L-\epsilon < f(x) < L+\epsilon,$
where $L$ is the limit value we set out to prove.

The function $f(x)=\frac1x$ comes with a pitfall, however:
if $\delta \geq |a|,$ then on the interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$
the values of $f$ are unbounded.
For example, if $a=1$ and we set $\delta=1,$ 
then we'd need to show that 
$0 < x < 2 \implies 1-\epsilon < \frac1x < 1+\epsilon$;
but we *cannot* do this, because that implication *is not true for any value of $\epsilon.$*

So we need a way somehow to pick a $\delta$ that is always small enough
*and never too large.*
The $\min$ function is an easy way to do this.
There are other ways, but they don't make our job much easier,
and some ways would make our job harder.

Answer (score 0):

It should **not** be $\delta=\min \{1, \frac {\epsilon}{a}\}$.

I should be (for example, as there are of course others correct choices of $\delta$) $\delta=\min \{\frac{|a|}{2}, \frac {\epsilon a^2}{2}\}$, and it's to make the proof rigorous for the case where $\epsilon$ is large, where unfortunately $x$ can be close to $0$, because you need to have a bound on $\frac{1}{|x|}$.

Note that $|x|\geq |a|-|x-a|$ due to the triangle inequality, so if $|x-a|<\delta \leq \frac{|a|}{2}$, we have $|x|>\frac{|a|}{2}$, so we have
$$\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}\right|=\frac{|x-a|}{|a|}\cdot \frac{1}{|x|}< \frac{2|x-a|}{a^2}<\frac{2\delta}{a^2}\leq \epsilon$$

$\delta=\min \{1, \frac {\epsilon}{a}\}$ fails if we choose $a=\frac{1}{2}$, because then we have for large $\epsilon$ that $0<|x-\frac{1}{2}|<1$, so $x$ can still be $0$.

Comment: large $\epsilon$ doesn't matter, just replace it with a small one wlog if it's too large.

Comment: @user363464 The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit requires you to prove a statement "for all $\epsilon$." You don't have the option to say, "I don't like that value of $\epsilon,$ send it back and get me a smaller one."

Comment: @DavidK sure you can. if you prove the result for small $\epsilon$, that for large $\epsilon$ is an immediate consequence.

Comment: @user363464 So what you're doing in effect is, you find $\epsilon_0$ such that your proof works for any $\epsilon\leq\epsilon_0.$ This is equivalent to substituting $\min\{\epsilon,\epsilon_0\}$ in the formula for $\delta.$ It works but it doesn't seem fundamentally simpler than the usual proof.

Comment: @DavidK it's a reduction of the general case to a special case, one in which you don't have to worry about your $\delta$ formula working for *all* values of $\epsilon$. Even intuitively, small values of $\epsilon$ are the only ones that matter in limits.

Comment: @user363464 Sure, but you still have to do _something_ to identify that special case. Some way or another, you have to make sure that $\delta$ is never too large, and you have to demonstrate that you have done so. Otherwise, since the implication _is not true_ for very large $\delta,$ you have an incorrect proof.

Comment: @user363464 If it really is easier to write the proof without using $\min$ function, the best way for you to make that point is to post an answer in which you prove that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac1x = \frac1a$ using your preferred method.